# What does +1 mean in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2, terminology

I sometimes see terms like +1 thrown around for example Zealots. I kinda figured out it's related to upgrades but what upgrade? Protoss have melee, armor, shields and air weapons. Does +1 mean all of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When ever casters use the term +X/+X They are referring to the weapon upgrade first, then the armor upgrade next. In your example +1 zealots would be a regular zealot with +1 weapon upgrade with nothing else.

You'll often hear them say casters saying "They're going for a quick +1 timing attack" which means that the person researching the weapon upgrade is building an attack for when the weapon upgrade finishes, giving them a timing window/advantage over their opponent (assuming the opponent doesn't have any upgrades).

Comment: +1/+1 means +1 attack and defense, with +1/+1/+1 meaning +1 to shields as well. This is because attack/defense are usually upgraded first, because they are regarded to provide more bang for the buck, and they are cheaper upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

[It](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft/+1_Zealot_Timing_Rush) appears to mean all of the tier 1 upgrades to weapons, armor and shields. Also seems to potentially include leg upgrades at least in the first game. It would not include air weapons.

Comment: Actually I believe in that article, +1 refers to attack only. The timing attack it centers around is referred to as: "when your legspeed/attack finish at the same time."